# My "matrix" is empty in Firestore when adding a object into an array

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to have the following structure:

```
-data (collection)
 -lottery (document)
  -win (data)
   -array
    -object
```

When I have inserted some data in object, something like "coins" : 100 and I click on add, I get this:

[image]

as you can see, there is no data inside of it. Refreshing the page still does not gives me any data. Is it possible to have my structure? If it isn't, why does the console does not show me any error? If there is no error, why can I not see my data?

Thanks.

edit: I think this is a bug of Firestore. When I insert a object into the empty 'win', the data is added. So it will not add the data when I initialise the object into the array, but it will afterwards. I will leave the question open for a Firebaser.

Comment: can you show me your code? I was able to I initialise the object into the array.